# How to get a file name inside a particular folder and pass that file name into a for loop index?

Tags: python, python-3.x, glob

I have a folder named **test** ,which contains **11.txt,12.txt,13.txt**

I need to read the content of the **test** folder , find the largest text file name and pass it into for loop starting index :

```
def find_largest_index(file_path):
  txt_files = glob.glob("*.*")
  #do smthing here to find the largest filename index
```

```
file_path = 'home/Documents/PythonCodeIsHere/test'
i = find_largest_index(file_path)
for page_i in pages_num[i-1:]:
    print(page_i)
```

Comment: Do you want to read the content of largest file only?

Comment: i just need the filename...in this case, just the number 13

Comment: Are every file in folder named as numeric? I mean as 11.txt,12.txt,13.txt...?

Comment: no..there are csv files and there is a running.txt inside test folder

Comment: what do you mean by "running .txt inside test folder"? Is there anything that differenciate this .txt file from the others?

Comment: this is the content of the test folder..11.txt,12.txt,13.txt,results.csv,running.txt

Comment: I have edited my answer, that should work now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import os

filenames = [int(filename[:-4]) for filename in os.listdir(file_path) if ( filename.endswith('.txt') and not filename.startswith('running') )]
i = max(filenames)
```

Comment: what is **filename[:-4]** @RandomGuy

Comment: just to delete the '.txt' part of the string and only keep the number ('11', '12', ...). As it is still a string you need to convert it to an int, hence the int(filename[:-4])